# Integrate jQuery plugin with LimeJS game engine

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, game-engine, isometric, limejs

I'm using the HTML5 game engine LimeJS and want to integrate a jQuery plugin for an isometric map. I added the tutorial script to a simple LimeJS program and there seems to be a conflict between LimeJS and jQuery. Both appear fine on the page, but the Lime script loses all interactivity when jQuery is included in the header.

Iso map plugin tutorial: http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/1298/browsergames_creating_a_basic_isometric_map/page-1/

Directory of my files (look at source of HTML files - lime isn't installed on server so not functioning): http://notlaura.com/limefiles/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run jQuery in noConflict mode and create an own scope for jQuery' s $ variable?

```
Query.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Full documentation is here 
[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)